# FBAR exchange rate question

Tags: united-states, fbar

I have a small, yet important question about FBAR, the policy regarding the reporting of foreign bank account.

The rule says that I only have to report when the aggregate amount exceeds 10,000 US dollars equivalent at any point of calendar year.

So my question is: Which exchange rate (for the currency) do I need to use? Is it the end-of-year exchange rate for the year 2015, DEC 31? (If I am concerned about the financial activities that have transpired since the beginning of 2015.)

Thanks bunch in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[This FBAR document suggests](https://www.fincen.gov/forms/files/FBAR%20Line%20Item%20Filing%20Instructions.pdf):

[image]

which eventually leads to [here](https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/fsreports/rpt/treasRptRateExch/treasRptRateExch_home.htm) which has the historical rates [here](https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/fsreports/rpt/treasRptRateExch/historicalRates.htm).

Comment: The first year we had to file a FBAR we had our taxes professionally done (a tax guy, not a storefront operation) and they used the IRS rate.  That's what I have done ever since on both the IRS and FBAR forms and neither has squawked about it.

Comment: So, if you hold Canadian dollars worth $9000 US from January to March, and then *close the account*, you'd *still* need to report the account if the CAN$ surged in value for the last few days in December?

Comment: @DJohnM no, that's not what it says. That's an acceptable way to do it, but any verifiable way of making the conversion is ok, too. If there was a large change against you between March and December, you can use any source. I use oanda for my filings with the IRS.